# What's the partition coefficient (D) of Nb for apatite?

Tags: geochemistry, petrology

Was there any experimental study that determined $D$ for apatite and silicate liquid?

The GERM Kd database only [lists one study with carbonatite liquid](http://earthref.org/KDD/e:41/?&sort=mineral), but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in the paper [Trace element partitioning between apatite and silicate melts](http://www.ierm.ed.ac.uk/homes/sklemme/publications/apatite_GCA_2006.pdf) (Prowatke and Klemme, 2006), where they present experimental apatite/melt trace element partition coefficients for a large number of trace elements, including $\ce{Nb}$.  The experiments were performed at pressures of 1 GPa and at a temperature of 1250 C.

What the experiments revealed were:

- An average of $D$ = 0.0018 for $\ce{Nb}$ (this value is an average of `Table 5: Trace element partition coefficients between apatite and different silicate melt` of the linked document).
- $D_{Nb} \approx D_{Ta}$
- The partition coefficient was not significantly affected by changing melt compositions.